# $_GET no funciona

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy empezando con php no conozco mucho del tema por favor cualquier respuesta sea bienvenida pero explicándolo todo al detalle : )

Quiero enviar el id de mi tabla Mysql por url de la siguiente manera:

```
<a href = "delete.php?id = <?php echo $row["id"]?>" 
   class = "btn btn-danger">
    <i fa-trash-alt"></i>
</a>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando le doy a borrar me muestra una página en blanco con la siguiente dirección:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código para realizar el borrado es el siguiente:

```
<?php
    include("db.php");

    if (isset($_GET["id"])){
        $id = $_GET["id"];
        $query = "DELETE FROM task WHERE id = $id";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        if (!$result){
            die("Query failed");
        }

        $_SESSION["message"] = "Task Removed Successfuly";
        $_SESSION["message_type"] = "danger";
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
?>
```

A mi parecer creo que el $_GET no esta funciónando y no se porque, y no se como hacer que funcione.

Comment: El problema no es PHP, si no de HTML, estás metiendo 2 espacios innecesario en la URL, que el navegador traduce como `%20`. Debería ser: `<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]?>"`

Comment: Ya elimine los espacios, pero sigue igual.

Comment: Si haces despues del *isset()* un ```var_dump($_GET["id"]); exit;``` te llega a imprimir el resultado?

Comment: No imprime nada es como si no entrara en el if()

Comment: De hecho no esta entrando en el primero IF, quita esta linea `if (isset($_GET["id"])){` y tambien su llave al final y prueba de nuevo. O bien al final agrega un else que imprima cualquier echo, de esta manera comprobarás que no está entrando en tu IF

Comment: Hola hace mucho intente borrar el if() y no me borraba la tarea solo me salía el mensaje de Task Removed Successfuly pero ahora si me funciona gracias : )

Comment: Es raro, ya que el *isset* solo comprueba si esta definido, entonces tampaco deberia de funcionar ```$id = $_GET["id"];```

Comment: Efectivamente no tiene ningun sentido quitar el isset... el error tiene pinta de que eran los espacios solamente... vuelvelo a poner y prueba de nuevo

Comment: Si el problema eran los espacios y también no se porque me dio lo de probar el código dentro de <?  ?> ahora lo tengo tal y como esta arriba en mi pregunta.

Comment: Si el problema eran los espacios esta pregunta es de las denominadas por "error tipográfico" y deberias eliminarla o bien dejarla hasta que el sistema la elimine por ese motivo (si reune suficientes votos de cierre).  Este tipo de preguntas no son de utilidad a nadie más y no deben permanecer en este sitio por eso.

Comment: Gracias aeroportugal estabas en lo cierto

Answer (score 3):

Prueba asi:

```
<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>"
```